# How to set_default_verify_paths from python?

Tags: python, macos, ssl, py2app

I build python app with py2app from Mac.
But then i run this app from another Mac, method `get_default_verify_paths`, does not work correct.
How to `set_default_verify_paths` in python?
I dont see params from this method, this is correct?